# Ruby, initialize class with argument

Tags: ruby

I have a scrubber that inherit from `Rails::Html::PermitScrubber`

```
class AmpScrubber < Rails::Html::PermitScrubber
  @paragraph = 0

  def initialize
    super
    @tags = %w(a em cite mark code sup sub kbd span p h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 strong s u br li ul figure figcaption table thead tbody tr td th source)
    @attributes = %w(style spellcheck hspace type data_type vspace contenteditable frameborder allowfullscreen allowtransparency scrolling align allowscriptaccess mozallowfullscreen cellspacing cellpadding webkitallowfullscreen )
  end
end
```

I use this scrubber in my view

```
= sanitize @content.meta_body, scrubber: AmpScrubber.new
```

I have to pass the content id in my scrubber, so I use

```
= sanitize @content.meta_body, scrubber: AmpScrubber.new(content_id: @content.id )
```

And I change the initializer

```
  def initialize(content_id)
    @content_id = content_id
    super
    @tags = %w(a em cite mark code sup sub kbd span p h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 strong s u br li ul figure figcaption table thead tbody tr td th source)
    @attributes = %w(style spellcheck hspace type data_type vspace contenteditable frameborder allowfullscreen allowtransparency scrolling align allowscriptaccess mozallowfullscreen cellspacing cellpadding webkitallowfullscreen )
  end
```

Result:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

Mmmh

Comment: Looks like you want `def initialize(content_id:)` i.e. a keyword argument (note the colon)

Answer (score 0):

Your initializer expects one single argument

```
def initialize(content_id)
```

but you pass a hash as an argument in this line

```
= sanitize @content.meta_body, scrubber: AmpScrubber.new(content_id: @content.id)
```

Just change that line to

```
= sanitize @content.meta_body, scrubber: AmpScrubber.new(@content.id)
```

Furthermore, you are calling `super` in your initializer. Calling to `super` implicitly passes the message argument from the `initialize` method in the subclass to the super class' `initialize` method. To avoid this, change your `initialize` method to

```
def initialize(content_id)
  @content_id = content_id
  super()
  @tags = %w(a em cite mark code sup sub kbd span p h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 strong s u br li ul figure figcaption table thead tbody tr td th source)
  @attributes = %w(style spellcheck hspace type data_type vspace contenteditable frameborder allowfullscreen allowtransparency scrolling align allowscriptaccess mozallowfullscreen cellspacing cellpadding webkitallowfullscreen )
end
```

Note the empty parentheses when calling `super`. This ensures that the super class' `initialize` method is called without any argument.

Comment: Passing a hash as an argument shouldn't be a problem; after all, it is still one argument. So, you shouldn't get a "wrong number of arguments" error. I suspect the OP may, in fact, *not* be passing a hash but a keyword argument, which (while somewhat confusing) would explain the error message, since it is only counting positional parameters and arguments.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are right. The keyword argument wasn't triggering the error message But the implicit `super` call. I updated my answer to address that too.